# What is fixed randomness and unfixed randomness?

Tags: randomness

I have found these notions recently in an article. What is fixed randomness ? What is unfixed randomness ?
Link of the article : http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.431.9034&rep=rep1&type=pdf
Page 8, part 4.1, Encrypt() algorithm.
Thank you!

Comment: The definition of $Encryption$ defines $(t,r_1)$ as inputs. It isn't immediately clear what the authors mean by *fixed randomness*, but looking ahead to the definition of game $G_8$, we see that *fixed randomness* is chosen by the challenger. Perhaps, and I'm guessing, $(t,r_1)$ are constants that are initialized as random values (in the game and by the administrator in applications). Maybe ask the authors for clarification.